# unzip the latest zipped file from a list of zipped files

Tags: shell-script

I want to write a script which gets the latest file from a list of zipped files and then unzip the file

I have tried `ls -t1 |  head -n 1 -exec unzip {}` -->  to get the latest zipped file. and unzipping it but it is not working

Comment: `head` doesn't have `-exec` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be mixing up `find` syntax and using it in the wrong place.

Typically you want to pass the filename to unzip, so you would use the syntax

```
unzip "$(....code.to.generate.filename...)"
```

You have the `ls` and `head` commands so the result would be

```
unzip "$(ls -t | head -n 1)"
```

Note the `"` around `$(...)` so that if you have spaces in the filename they'll be kept consistent.

Of course this will break if the newest file is a directory or has a RETURN character in it :-)